# Mouseenter event in, on, with drag event bad issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, drag-and-drop

I'm using [drag and drop](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event) jquery events. I have some problem with drag event. I need to add some border to some element on witch I'm currently dragging. I have a weird response because if I do my drag fast I see the border add action, but for a one moment and it's disappears. So this is my code and example of this issue. Can anybody help?

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.drag')
        .drag("start",function( ev, dd ){
            return $( this ).clone()
                .css("opacity", .75 )
                .appendTo( this.parentNode );
        } )
        .drag(function( ev, dd ){
            $( dd.proxy ).css({
                top: dd.offsetY,
                left: dd.offsetX
            } );
            $('.drop').on('mouseenter', function(){
                $(this).css('border','3px solid #ccc');
            });
            $('.drop').on('mouseleave', function(){
                $(this).css('border','none');
            });
        })
        .drag("end",function( ev, dd ){
            $( dd.proxy ).remove();
        });
    $('.drop').drop(function( ev, dd ){
        $( this ).toggleClass('dropped');
    } );
} );
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ydc8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mouseenter dose not bubble](http://jsfiddle.net/A5baq/5/)

If dragging and mouse over .drag, .drag prevent .drop mouseenter.

Fast mouse move leave .drag and fire .drop mouseenter.

[improved sample](http://jsfiddle.net/A5baq/5/)

```
jQuery(function($){
var drop = $(".drop");
var dropDummy = $(".drop")
.clone()
.css({
    'position' : 'absolute'
    , 'opacity' : 0
    , 'top' : $(".drop").position().top
    , 'left' : $(".drop").position().left
    , 'z-index' : -1
     })
.appendTo('body')
;
$('.drag')
    .drag("start",function( ev, dd ){
        return $( this ).clone()
            .css("opacity", .75 )
            .css("width", "30px")
            .appendTo( this.parentNode );
    } )
    .drag(function( ev, dd ){
        dropDummy.css('z-index', 100);
        $( dd.proxy ).css({
            top: ev.pageY,
            left: ev.pageX
        } )
        ;
    })
    .drag("end",function( ev, dd ){
        dropDummy.css('z-index', -1);
        $( dd.proxy ).remove();
    });

drop.drop(function( ev, dd ){
    $( this ).toggleClass('dropped');
} );

dropDummy
.on('mouseenter', function() {
    drop.css('border','3px solid #ccc');
})
.on('mouseleave', function() {
    drop.css('border','none');
})
;
```

} );

add drop dummy and if dragged, dummy z-index set 100.

Comment: your improvement has probrem?

Comment: yeah, now when the elements are in the same block there is some problem with this functionality

Comment: you narrow .drag width? now setting mousemove on .drag. so if mouse dose not move over .drag, .drag mousemove not fired. set mousemove on .drop

Comment: I don't get it, can you improve Fiddle?

Comment: if you have not to set mouse position over .drag, .drop mouseenter and mouseleave can be used. http://jsfiddle.net/A5baq/